# What is localserver? What is it used for?

Tags: apache2

I"m a beginner to Linux.

I installed apache2. I run my html file in my browser as a localhost. It runs successfully

But I have some confusion that I can still run my html file without the use of the server on my browser. What is the use of local server. What does it do to my html file that the browser alone cannot do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have installed a local web server on your development machine for two purposes:

- To test your web sites the way that a user somewhere on the internet would see them. They would obviously not have access to your filesystem directly, so you want to make sure that the web sites work when accessed over the internet.
- To enable functionality which is not available without a web server, such as serving pages over HTTPS, using PHP (or some other language) scripting, setting and getting cookies, or using URL rewriting rules or redirects.